# Panel Control Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, panel

I am just wondering if anybody knows anything about the speed of the WinsForms panel control relative to the number of controls placed in it.

I have panels that I need to populate with hundreds of controls and it seems to slow down exponentially.  I have tried making the panel invisible when populating it and this doesn't seem to help.

I am asking for two reasons:

1. To determine if this slow down is the result of the panel control or
   a quite complicated (for me) bit of code that is handling the panel
   and adding the items to it.
2. If it *is* the result of the panel, then I would like to determine if there
   is anything I can do about it.  I am quite a ways into the project
   and the project depends upon panels that contain these controls.

Thanks for your time.

My level of expertise is fairly amateur BTW.

Comment: What you need is [`profiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

Comment: @Popinjay Most time if an application becomes slow, the reason is on data handling or sth. Please show us, how you populate data to your controls. If you have many panels and each of them got over 100 controls, the rendering could need a significant amount of time. But we need some code to help you in this case. Also would it great to know, what you mean by slow. Do you mean 500ms or 5sec or maybe 20sec etc. Give us an area please.

Comment: Several seconds, depending on the number of controls.

I use a panel to create my own list box which can do things that a normal windows form list box cannot.  The list items can contain buttons, be multi-colored, and be dragged up and down in the list.  (This is also why I do not load controls as the user needs them...they need to see the whole list.)

This custom control has quite a few features and I am not an especially efficient programmer, however, and is very large.  Far too large to paste here.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your code to load the panel. Moreover you need to add more information in your problem about the controls and loading process. With general assumptions, to speed up you can do :-

1. **Lazy load**. User will not interact with hundreds of control at a given time. So, load the controls on demand.
2. Populate the controls in **background thread**, and make them ready just before they are required to be shown.
3. Load them based on the **priority of the user interaction**.